# JMeter - Api GET Request - Response says: No known way to render data, Status Code is 200 though

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Performing GET Requests which returns a JSON response.
JMeter is getting Statua code 200 but in Response, it says: *NO way found to render data.*
I tried the same request in POSTMAN and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not telepathic enough to state why exactly request in Postman works and request in JMeter doesn't, in general the answer would be: **you're not sending the same requests**.

Double check the following:

1. Request [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), if request parameters have some non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) data it needs to be [url-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)
2. Request [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), in particular [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). In JMeter request headers can be added/modified using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)
3. Request body (if any), again [encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) might be very important

---

In general given your request works in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-)

   [image]
3. Run your request in Postman
4. That's it, JMeter should capture the request under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Thanks @dmitri T.  I followed your approach and recorded the postman using JMeter proxy. Compared to both the requests, header, encoding and all parameters. I don't see any difference. The result is still the same.  *Status Code: 200 and Response body says: No known way to render data *

Comment: If you don't see the differences, maybe we can detect them. If you need further assistance - please share 2 .har files, one from JMeter and another from Postman

Comment: Resolved.  I am not sure how important these headers are, so I excluded Accept and Cache-Control headers since I was not using it in Postman. I added these 2 and I am getting a response.  Thanks, @Dmitri T

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the Postman and JMeter requests. 
Postman was working without passing Accept and Cache-Control headers but Jmeter requires it.
After adding these 2 in headers, I started getting a response. And I changed few JMeter properties to avoid checking the response size check.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started working after adding below content in request header. specially accept attribute.

```
  "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
```

and

```
  "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
```